# Is it possible to use attachfile package in any documentclass or just in articles?

Tags: moderncv, attachfile, documentclass

I have seen some `.tex` documents using `\usepackage{attachfiles}`, but all of them were `article`s. Now I am working on a `moderncv` document class and `\usepackage{attachfiles}` returns an error.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,spanish,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{attachfile}

\moderncvstyle{casual} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} % For the 'classic' style, uncomment to adjust the width of the space allocated to your name
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
```

And the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.37 \begin{document}
The package hyperref has already been loaded with options:
[,]
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
[unicode]
Adding the global options:
,,unicode
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
Try typing <return> to proceed...
```

Comment: If your real question is how to get attachfiles working in moderncv you should make a complete but small example that demonstrates the error and could be used for tests.

Comment: Nothing in a quick glance at the package documentation makes me think that `attachfiles` was written specifically only for `article` or other standard classes. But it is not reasonable to assume that the developer tested his package with all available document classes. If you are specifically interested in `moderncv`, please edit your question with a minimal example document that reproduces the issue. The answer to the question in your title is certainly yes.

Comment: What LaTeX format are you using? As far as I recall, `attachfiles` doesn't work with XeLaTeX (but does work with LuaLaTeX).

Comment: Please don't repost your smaller example.  [edit] this one to be smaller.  The error makes it look like two different things are trying to load the hyperref package.  My bet would be `moderncv` and `attachfiles`.  The error message suggests that you add `unicode` to your options for the `documentclass`.  Have you done that?  What happens?

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load attachfile with the option unicode:

```
   \usepackage[unicode]{attachfile}
```

Comment: Just to explain why this helps: `moderncv` loads `\RequirePackage[unicode]{hyperref}` in an `\AtEndPreamble` hook and `attachfile` loads `hyperref` at loading time and passes on any options to it. So loading `attachfile` with the without options loads `\usepackage{hyperref}` which clashes with the `\RequirePackage[unicode]{hyperref}` later on, but if `attachfile` is loaded with the `unicode` option it loads `\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}` which does not clash.

Comment: @Sergio Great! If this answered your question, please consider accepting the answer, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers. And if you are having trouble with the format of this site, you may want to have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/35864